# How Spring-Hibernate integration and Spring+JPA+Hibernate differs?

Tags: java, spring, orm

I am confused with Spring-Hibernate integration and Spring+JPA+Hibernate. How it differs & which has more advantage to use in our coding?

Answer (score 0):

The Java Persistence API (JPA) is a Java specification for accessing, persisting, and managing data between Java objects / classes and a relational database. Hibernate is a ORM - Object Relational Mapping library which follows JPA specification. Spring-Hibernate integration involves Spring directly making use of Hibernate; there is no layer in between. Spring-JPA-Hibernate involves Spring using entity manager such as LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and Hibernate as ORM tool (implementor of JPA specifications). JPA is just a specification, meaning there is no implementation and Hibernate provides that implementation. One should always prefer Spring-JPA as it would be possible to switch to any other JPA implementation in the future during life cycle of project. No direct dependencies with Hibernate classes/jars/annotations as code would make use of JPA annotations/classes. Other than Hibernate, many other JPA implementations exist such as Toplink, OpenJPA etc..